# Python: Why changing `from constants import API_TOKEN to `import constants` causes errors?

Tags: python, python-import

I'm using PyCharm and Python 3.10. I've had a constant, `API_TOKEN`, defined with an assignment statement in a separate file, `constants.py` and imported it with:
`from constants import API_TOKEN`
That has been working.

I'd like to add more "importable" constants to `constants.py`; just to make sure that would work, before adding them I changed the import statement to
`import contants`
That single change caused PyCharm to generate an `Unresolved reference 'API_TOKEN'` error on each of the two references, and an `Unused import statement 'import constants'` warning.

Comment: Can you show your code? Are you still referring to it as `API_TOKEN` or did you update your code to use `constants.API_TOKEN` when you switched to `import constants`?

Comment: @wkl I edited the question title to change the constant name to the actual one I'm using from the abstract `a_constant` in the original title. BUT constants.API_TOKEN is the answer. Would you like to answer, or shall I, with credit to you?

Comment: Feel free to answer it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making the change to the `import` I neglected to add `constants.` to the references. So:

```
import constants
...
constants.API_TOKEN  # use the value
```

Thanks to @wkl for the answer in a comment to the question!